# Using Cognito federated identity with API Gateway and postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

My objective is for my user to sign-in using Cognito and get a temporary IAM role that allows them HTTP access to specific methods in API Gateway.

What I have done so far:

- set up my user pool
- set up my identity pool
- set up IAM roles for authenticated and unauthenticated users
- set up a group with an IAM role allowing access to POST to (at
  present) all API gateway methods.
- put my user into the group
- set up my API Gateway method to use `IAM` authorization

I can sign-in via Cognito in my browser using a front end created via Amplify.

When I check in the browsers local storage I can see I have the following:

- `idToken`
- `accessToken`
- `refreshToken`

When I have done this using a `COGNITO` authorizer on the API Gateway all I had to do in Postman was add a `Authorization` header and paste in the `idToken`. This gave me access to the API.

How can I test my API using Postman with IAM authorization?

I am still given the tokens, but now pasting them in to the `Authorization` header gives me an error message:

`Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header.`

I have read that I need to sign requests but I am unsure how I would do this from my web browser based application.

Even if I can do that how can I test in Postman, or is this no longer possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the requests can still be made via Postman but they must be in Amazon's Sigv4 format.

The solution is as follows.

1. Get the `accessKey`, `secretKey` and `sessionToken` returned from the sign-in process*.
2. In Postman, for the request, select the `Authorization` tab and for `type` choose `AWS Signature`.
3. Enter the `accessKey`, `secretKey` and `sessionToken` retrieved from step 1 into the corresponding fields in Postman.
4. You also need to set the `AWS Region` e.g. `eu-central-1`.
5. Press SEND.

Postman will create the appropriate Sigv4 request to call your API. You can see the result of this in Postman's `Headers` tab for the request where it will have automatically created the required headers.

*I added **temporary** code into my React/Amplify application to do this.

Comment: Is it possible to post the code spinet for React/Amplify application that do this process